# Unable to save custom order attribute

Tags: sql, setup-script

I've created a custom order attribute in my extension's setup script like this:

```
$setup->addAttribute('order', 'my_custom_attribute', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
    'global' => 0,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
));
```

When I look into *eav_attribute* table in the DB after running this script I can see that a new entry has been created with the options listed above and assigned to the *entity_type_id* of *4*, which is the *sales/order* entity model in this installation.

Now when I do the following, I get an empty result:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(90);
$order->setData('my_custom_attribute', 'test');
$order->save();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(90);
echo $order->getData('my_custom_attribute'); // NULL
```

Is there a step that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using wrong class during setup. You need to make sure that `$setup` is instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup` class. I'm not sure but you are probably using `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.

If there is no `my_custom_attribute` row in `sales_flat_order` table you are probably using wrong setup class. You can also remove `my_custom_attribute` from `eav_attribute` table.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have been one issue with my code. However I'm still unable to write to the custom attribute: `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(90)->setData('my_custom_attribute', 'something')->save()`. Do you perhaps know why this doesn't work?

Comment: 1) Verify that `my_custom_attribute` column exists in `sales_flat_order` 2) Try flushing cache

Comment: Ah, flushed the cachees and reindexed all tables, not it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me. If you used that exact code then you're missing a quote after `attribute` in your attribute name.

```
$setup->addAttribute('order', 'my_custom_attribute, array(
```

The only other thing would be to make sure the order ID exists.

Here is the full install script I used to install your attribute:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'my_custom_attribute', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
    'global' => 0,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks for testing my code. I changed the error with the wrong setup class, and now I can see that a column for *my_custom_attribute* has been added to the *sales_flat_order* table. However, I'm still unable to write anything to that column like this: `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(90)->setData('my_custom_attribute', 'something')->save()`. Did that work for you?

Comment: Yes that part worked fine for me.  I was able to save and retrieve.  Just make sure entity_id 90 exists.

Comment: Ah, flushed the cachees and reindexed all tables, not it's working. Thanks! I have to however accept the other guy's answer as he was two minutes earlier.

Comment: No worries!  I'm just glad you got it resolved